# How can enforce and reinforce have slightly different spelling and still be valid?

Tags: orthography

When I initially wrote *inforce* the dictionary told me that *enforce* was the correct word.

However, when I wrote *reenforce* it told me that *reinforce* was the word I was looking for.

So, I searched this on-line, but didn't find anything useful except [this post](http://snarkygrammarguide.blogspot.com/2010/09/enforce-vs-inforce-only-one-is-word.html?m=1)

Can someone elaborate on this further?

Comment: Oxford Lexico says of [**reinforce**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/reinforce): Origin Late Middle English from French renforcer, influenced by inforce, an obsolete spelling of enforce; the sense of providing military support is probably from Italian rinforzare.

Comment: Spellings of unstressed vowels are irrelevant, since they're all reduced anyway. Consequently the spellings will vary. Almost nobody notices. Even computers don't care.

Comment: Your spellchecker is rather poor, I'm afraid. However, you have to run your fingers through some seven centuries of variations in spellings of *enforse, enfoarce, enforce, inforse, inforce, rainforce, reenfors, reënforce, re-enforce, reenforce, re-enforce, reinforce*, and several more besides those to have any hope of making some sense of it all. I lament to inform you that many more of those are still in occasional current use than are dreamt of by your mindless spellchecker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason the spellings are different is that **reinforce** does *not* mean "to **enforce** again". The word [enforce](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/enforce) is defined by the Macmillan dictionary and others as

> to make sure that a law or rule is obeyed by people

or

> to make sure that something happens or is done

[Reinforce](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/reinforce), however is defined as

> to make an idea, belief or feeling stronger

or

> to make a situation, process or type of behaviour stronger and more likely to continue

or

> to make a building, structure or object stronger

or

> to make a group of soldiers, police etc stronger by adding more people or equipment to it.

In short *enforce* means to ensure that a law or rule is obeyed or complied with, while *reinforce* means to make something stronger in some way.

There is no word "to inforce" meaning to make strong initially, if a building is made strong initially, say by the use of *reinforced concrete* in its construction it is said to be "strongly built" and, if it is later strengthened, it is then said to be *reinforced*.

Similarly there is no word *reenforce* meaning to enforce again, perhaps after a regulation has been allowed to lapse. If it was needed it might be hyphenated to give re-enfoce but the situation probably does not arise frequently enough for such a word to become universally understood.

Comment: This isn't really correct. The verb spelt *reenforce* certainly exists, and is the elder of the two spellings. Their histories are complex, with *reinforce* coming from the verb *inforce* as it was sometimes spelt at the time. Two OED citations follow: **1566**  W. Painter *Palace of Pleasure* I. l. f. 297  — The chaste hearte of this woman, did reenforce and fortefie her courage in double wise. **1997** J. Ryan *Dismantling Mr Doyle* viii. 95 —  She added that episode..to a number of others which..re-enforced her sense of inadequacy.

Comment: @tchrist The only comments I can make are that the sixteenth century example pre-dates standardised spelling; that the twentieth century example is hyphenated as I suggested and the latter is, probably, a misprint for "reinforced" anyway.